# Tweepy StreamListener to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tweepy

I'm a newbie on python and I'm trying to develop an app that retrieves data from Twitter with Tweepy and the Streaming APIs and converts the data on a CSV file.
The problem is that this code doesn't create an output CSV file, maybe because I should set the code to stop when it achieves for eg. 1000 tweets but I'm not able to set this stop point

here's the code

```
import sys
import tweepy
import csv

#pass security information to variables
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""


#use variables to access twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#create an object called 'customStreamListener'

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print (status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text)


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream


streamingAPI = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
streamingAPI.filter(track=['Dallas', 'NewYork'])

def on_status(self, status):
    with open('OutputStreaming.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Author,Date,Text')
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text])
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your second `on_status` function is not inside the `CustomStreamListener` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function that you are trying to write the csv with is never called.
I assume you wanted to write this code in `CustomStreamListener.on_status`.
Also, you have to write the titles to the file once (outside the stream  listener).
Take a look at this code:

```
import sys
import tweepy
import csv

#pass security information to variables
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""


#use variables to access twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#create an object called 'customStreamListener'

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print (status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text)
        # Writing status data
        with open('OutputStreaming.txt', 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text])


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

# Writing csv titles
with open('OutputStreaming.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Author', 'Date', 'Text'])

streamingAPI = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
streamingAPI.filter(track=['Dallas', 'NewYork'])
```

Comment: you are right I was wrong but now it seems there is a problem with the characters. When I try to run the code print only some tweets data and  then return this code 
'UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f44d' in position 111: character maps to <undefined>' This happens when meet some tweet where there are some special characters how can I fix this problem. More over haw can I stop the serching of tweets for eg. afeter 1000 tweets?

Comment: It probably occurs since it cannot print the unicode part of the tweet text.
Try using `status.text.encode('utf-8')` instead of just `status.text` (Both in the printing line and in the line with `writerow`).
Also, open the file with utf-8 encoding: 
`with open('OutputStreaming.txt', 'w'', encoding="utf8") as f:`.
For the other question (limit to 1000 tweets), please post another question.

Comment: Also, if the answer was helpful, please accept it so future users who encounter your problem will be able to find ths solution easily.