# Converting tweets into a csv or xlsx file

Tags: python, twitter, pycharm, tweepy

I am doing project for class to see the correlation between Tesla's stock price and Elon Musk's tweet frequency since 2016.

I got the stock data using pandas_datareader and have used tweeps to get a few of Elon Musk's most recent tweets.

This is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


startDate = datetime(2016,1,1)
endDate = datetime.today()

tesla = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', startDate, endDate)

tesla = tesla[["Adj Close"]]


tesla.to_excel('Tesla.xlsx')

plt.plot(tesla)
plt.show()



import tweepy


consumer_key = "MY KEY"
consumer_secret = "MY KEY"
access_key = "MY KEY"
access_secret = "MY KEY"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

name = "elonmusk"
tweetCount = 5

results = api.user_timeline(id=name, count=tweetCount)

for tweet in results:
    print(tweet.text)
```

I am looking to get the tweets into a csv or xlsx file with two columns, one with the date info and the other with the tweets.

The code returns the following:

```
@jlist ♥️ 
@moyn1ckzanyat правда
@v_g_fischer @4thFromOurStar Coming soon
@4thFromOurStar Already have one
Respawn++ https://twitter.com/cleantechnica/status/1119828529422770177

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Take a look at Python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Comment: add some lines of your received stock data and tweets to your answer, i don't know depend on what you wanna put them in the rows

Comment: Related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768219/tweepy-crawl-live-streaming-tweets-and-save-in-to-a-csv-file